# CORS problem : image not displaying in Chrome, Edge whereas it works in firefox

Tags: html, image, policy

I want to display an image in my website that came from another domain. To do this, I add the attribute **referrerPolicy** to my image in my HTML code:

```
<img referrerPolicy="no-referrer" src="http://login:password@www.otherdomain.net/image.jpg" />
```

It works with firefox, but not with Edge and Chrome.

When I debug the browser to see the network, I have the status for image.jpg set to **(blocked:origin)**

my website use SSL, whereas, as you can see, the website that host the image is not. (I don't think it is the problem, but..).

Any idea?

Comment: Why would you expose Login info by loading a protected image??

Comment: I agree that is not a secure way to access the image, but do you think this is the cause of my problem?

Comment: What is returned as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` in the response header from that other server, when you do your http request?

Comment: this is not the cause of your problems, but this way you are creating more problems to yourself in regard to your relationship with that domain, as if you put these credentials on a public server, they will get picked up by anyone who is visiting your webpage, and then be used to do additional harm FROM YOUR ACCOUNT (your credentials) towards that remote server... and then you will suffer blockage, or fees (if the service is paid) ... in any regard, exposing credentials is a VERY BAD idea...

Comment: there is no response, the console says "Failed to load response data" 

And the header of the request to the image is :

Request URL: http://login:password@www.otherdomain.net/image.jpg
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
Provisional headers are shown
Referer